# Режимы сборки Debug и Release в Visual Studio и C++

Tags: c++, отладка, visual-studio-2013

Пишу в Visual Studio 2013. Есть, значит, функция, которая должна выполняться в потоке:

```
void click(int &a, int &flag){
do{
    a = _getch();
} while (flag != 0);
}
```

И есть функция main, в которой объявляется поток (класс thread) и при нажатии на клавиатуру отображается код кнопки.

```
int keyState = 0;
void main()
{
int fl = 1;
thread input(click, ref(keyState), ref(fl));
while (true){
    while (keyState == 0){}
    cout << keyState << endl;
    keyState = 0;
}

system("pause");
```

}

Пока собираю в Debug, то все идет нормально, но стоит собрать проект в Release, как вся программа не работает. Причина в строчке

```
while (keyState == 0){}
```

Стоит добавить в тело цикла любой вывод на экран

```
while (keyState == 0){ cout << ""; }
```

как все начинает работать.
Меня как новичка (2 курс универа) это просто приводит в ступор. В чем причина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор не "видит", что данная переменная может изменятся в другом потоке.
В режиме Release включается более жесткая оптимизация и проверка выкидывается, как ненужная(значение то не меняется...).

Нужно "сказать" компилятору, что нужно каждый раз считывать ее из основной памяти.

Основные способы это использование [volatile](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) и (что мне кажется более правильным) [std::atomic](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Пример использования `std::atomic`

```
#include <atomic>
//...
std::atomic<int> keyState(0);
//В 1м потоке
while(keyState.load()==0) {}
// 2й поток
if (some) {
    keyState.store(new_value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Остается только непонятным, почему проверка все же ведется, если в теле цикла применяется вывод на консоль. При любых других операциях, программа стоит. Особенность потока вывода?

Comment: Там может быть ситуация, что при отсутствии кода в цикле значение берется из кеша процессора(т.е. код не видит изменений в RAM), а при наличии кода  кеш обновляется и изменения становятся видимыми. P.S. [курс по параллельному программированию](http://www.lektorium.tv/course/23050), советую

Comment: atomic и volatile - это, в общем-то, совершенно разные вещи. В данном случае следует объявлять именно как `volatile` - здесь важен именно тот факт, что переменная может быть изменена некоторым не известным компилятору образом. Насколько предложенный метод с опросом в цикле плох - это тема отдельного разговора... В литературе - Мейерс очень настаивает на том, чтобы не путать `atomic` и `volatile`.